# setting text in edit box using variable

Tags: winapi, unicode, sendmessage

I got simple function which is defined like this:

```
void addEndText(HWND hEdit, LPCWSTR newText)
{
int TextLen = SendMessage(hEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)TextLen, (LPARAM)TextLen);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, FALSE, (LPARAM)newText);
}
```

when I call it in this way:

```
 addEndText(editHandler1, L"TEST TEXT")
```

everything seems to be good and work properly. But when i just do
this in this way:

```
addEndText(editHandler1, (LPCWSTR)buff)
```

where buff is char array, in my edit box appears weird characters instead of what was in buff. I know this is because of coding schema. But I dont know how can I make it working. Thanks for any respond

Comment: What does the variable `buff` look like? If it's really a plain `char[]`, you need to make it an array of `WCHAR` to be of wide characters (like what you do with the `L` prefix to your test string). Or even cleaner, an array of `TCHAR`.

Comment: Evil, evil cast.  It only stopped the compiler from telling you that you were doing it wrong.  It didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Your variable must be a wide string, wchar_t[].  If you have a char[] then you must *convert* it, mbtowc().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `buff` is a `char[]` or `char*`, you cannot simply type-cast it to a `LPCWSTR` (ie `const wchar_t*`). You have to convert its data from `char` to `wchar_t`, such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()`.